# Error en el registro de usuario, PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, phpmailer

Tengo un error en la linea 150, en la parte de arr['success'].
El error que me dice xampp es

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string
> on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\registro.php:50 Stack trace: #0
> {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\registro.php on line 50.

```
if(count($errors) == 0) {
        $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret
        &response=$captcha");

        $arr = json_encode($response, TRUE);

        if($arr['success']) {
            $pass_hash = hashPassword($password);
            $token = generateToken();

            $registro = registraUsuario($usuario, $pass_hash, $nombre, $email, $activo, $token, $tipo_usuario);
            if($registro > 0) {
                $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/login/activar.php?id='.$registro.'&val='.$token;

                $asunto = 'Activar cuenta - Sistema de Usuarios';
                $cuerpo = 'Estimado $nombre <br /> <br /> Para continuar con el proceso
                de registro, es indispensable de click en la siguiente liga
                <a href="$url">Activar cuenta</a>';

                if(enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo)) {
                    echo "Para terminar el proceso de registro siga las intrucciones que le hemos enviado
                    la direccion de correo electrónico: $email";

                    echo "<br><a href='index.php'>Iniciar secion</a>";
                    exit;
                } else {
                    $errors[] = 'Error al enviar email'; 
                }

            } else {
                $errors = 'Error al registrar';
            }
        } else {
            $errors[] = 'Error al comprobar Captcha';
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Y, ¿cuál es esa famosa línea `50`?

Comment: if($arr['success'])

Comment: Pues depura tu respuesta poniendo un `var_dump($response);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Considera además que `json_encode()` devuelve una cadena, no un array. Suponiendo que obtienes un json válido en la respuesta, deberías hacer algo así para convertir dicha cadena en un array: **`$arr = json_decode( json_encode($response), TRUE );`**

Comment: Hice el var_dump($response), pero no muestra nada.

Comment: ¿Intentando lo que sugerí en el anterior comentario no funciona? En cuanto al `var_dump` me extraña mucho que no muestre nada, aunque sea `NULL` u otra cosa ¿?